# Converting Raster to Polygon/Shapefile using ArcMap without Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have a floating point raster file which I want as a polygon for visual purposes so I can trace/trim/etc. the polygon (unless there is a way I can trace the raster?).

Looking into other posts on here most tools recommended require spatial analyst or 3D analyst which I do not have access to.

I don't need to retain any information from the raster, just an outline of the shape itself but as it is a large complex shape it would not be easy to manually draw so is there a way to convert it to a polygon?

I am using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: The tool is Polygon to Raster but that requires an integer raster to run, spatial analyst is used to convert floating point to integer, commonly with either Con or IsNull, that is your sticking point. If you're inflexible on Esri SA then you might need to expand your horizon to GDAL_Calc or using arcpy convert the raster to a numpy array then set the values to 0 or 1 for having/not having a valid value then write numpy array to raster. Do either of these options sound desirable to you?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 is on the ancient side.  The ArcPy implementation and Python release are sufficiently elderly that you're unlikely to get much assistance from folks using newer, more stable releases. You're probably better off using a modern QGIS than an ancient ArcGIS.

Comment: If it's not millions of cells, convert to points, buffer by 1.5 cell size dissolving all. Perhaps do a negative buffer on result.

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554 - check this out. Looks this uses just basic ArcCatalog tools.

Comment: @enolah they are using raster calculator, i.e. tool from spatial analyst.